# vector relationships (find a vector in same direction).

Tags: vectors

Given  $b=i-j-k$ find another vector of length 5 that points in the same direction

no idea how i would limit the length and get the same direction.

Comment: Find a vector of length 1 in that direction and multiply by 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The length of a vector is the square root of the sum of the squares of its components.

So, assuming that $i = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$, $j = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$, and $k = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$, then

$$b  =\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ -1\end{pmatrix}.$$

This has a length equal to $\|b\| = \sqrt{1^2+(-1)^2+(-1)^2} = \sqrt{3}$.

To get something of length $5$, you need to multiply $b$ by a scalar $\alpha$ such that $\|\alpha b\| = 5$. Now, given that $\|\alpha b\| = |a|\|b\|$, can you find such a scalar?

Comment: so what you are saying is to obtain a scalar product of a and b such that it equals $5$? or is it $5\sqrt{3}$

Comment: Find a scalar $\alpha$ and multiply it by $b$ to make a new vector, $\alpha b$. Now, we want the magnitude of the new vector $\alpha b$ to be equal to $5$. This allows us to compute the scalar.

Comment: Oh i see. So then multiply $i,j,k$ by $5\sqrt{3}/3$ and the magnitude is then 5. Is that it?

Comment: Plug it in and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

A vector in the same direction is a scalar multiple.  Thus you need to find some $a$ such that $\vert ai-aj-ak\vert=5$.  Can you do that?